# Require password from current user on front-end form?

Tags: plugin-development, users, plugins, password, usermodel

I have a controller that handles some font-end form validation. From that controller I’d like to require the current (already logged in) user’s password to update any field. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the user to have an authenticated session to update any field?  Or you want them to not only have an authenticated session, but to re-enter their password so you can verify it before updating any field?

Comment: @BradBell re-enter the password to verify. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd create a Craft [plugin](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins) with a [controller](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/controllers) that has an [action](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/controllers#posting-to-controller-actions), say `actionSaveForm()`.

Your controller would look for a `password` POST variable and if that existed, validate that against the currently logged in user's account to make sure it was a match.  If so, continue onto Craft's `saveUser` or `saveEntry`, etc. (whatever you're using the form for, otherwise, return a validation error message.

Roughly like this:

```
public function actionSaveForm()
{
    $this->requirePostRequest();
    craft()->userSession->requireLogin();

    $password = craft()->request->getRequiredPost('password');
    {# grab anything else you need from POST #}

    $currentUser = craft()->userSession->getUser();

    if (craft()->users->validatePassword($currentUser->password, $password))
    {
        {# saveEntry, saveUser, etc. then redirect #}
    }

    // Invalid Password
    craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables(array(
        'error' => "Invalid Password"
    ));
}
```